# How to select every second row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to select every second row in Oracle.

My coding is L `select * from people where count(peopleid) mod 2=0;` but it doesent work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "every second row", because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you have a column that specifies the ordering, such as `peopleid`, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (order by peopleid) as seqnum
      from people p
     ) p
where mod(seqnum, 2) = 0;
```

EDIT:

You could do the same thing with `rownum`, but it needs to go in the subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, rownum as seqnum
      from people p
      order by orderid
     ) p
where mod(seqnum, 2) = 0;
```

The `order by` is optional, but the rows could be evaluated in any order without it.